# How to capture 1/10000 part of second

Tags: java, android, time

I am going to design an app where i want to take decision based on fractional part of seconds.
Suppose i have counter that start from zero and move onward and now i keep track of milliseconds in background,let's say i have capture this fractional part of(like below) second or two or three seconds and then want to do some task like send data or show a message or  something else.

```
0.4958 sec or
2.9958 sec
```

how can i capture such instant mean fraction of seconds or time in background.
i tried a lot but did not succeed.any one have any idea
thank you.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you want. Do you want the fraction representation of the time. Show what you have tried and explain what you got and what you wanted

Comment: have you checked/tried  `System.currentTimeMillis` [currentTimeMillis](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis())

Comment: sorry for my bad english sir...basically i want to start the time counter and capture some specific instant of time like shown above or like 0.4958 or 5.4958 instant of time...thank you for your interest.

Comment: how can i capture this instant sir.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`System.nanoTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--)

> Returns the current value of the running Java Virtual Machine's high-resolution time source, in nanoseconds.

```
long nanoTime = System.nanoTime();
double inSeconds = (double) nanoTime / 1000000000.0;
```

Comment: but how can i format it into this decimal form like #.#### sec

Comment: `double seconds = (double) nanoTime / 1000000000.0;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the static methods available in `java.lang.System` classes such as `System.currentTimeMillis()` `System.nanoTime` both of these two methods are static and long